# deploying only rpm package with maven and nexus

Tags: java, maven

My use case is simple. I am using maven-rpm-plugin to build and deploy a package on a nexus repository. Currently the deploy phase upload the jar file and the rpm to their respective nexus repos. I am looking for a way to skip the deployment phase only for the jars since i am using only the rpm in production. I still need to package those jar to make the RPM.

Comment: What is so bad about those jar's`Just keep that way it's simpler...and if you only use the rpm ...where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that i have been told to limit the disk usage on the nexus server to the strict minimum.

Comment: Sorry using a repository manager and discussing about disk usage is these days simply rediclious...but on the other hand you are wasting a large number of time to find a non conventionally solution which in the end will cost more than the disk space....furthermore will confuse other people while looking into this project..

Comment: What would be the conventional solution then ?

Comment: As I mentioned before simple deploy all artifacts to your repository manager ...and than it's done...solved by using conventions etc.